# webpack a few packages cooperation

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have own base package. This is Reackt 15.6, I use ES6 and webpack 2 to make vanilla JS.
This package is html builder and will use many times for a few pages. For each pages I need to: standard html components + custom components.

Perfect situation would be:
 - core package written in React (ES6) after translate by webpack
 - config file with custom components list
 - package with custom components. Components in React (ES6) translate by webpack to Vanilla JS

And core package use components from custom package without edit core. Only one idea in my head is something like

```
for(x in y){
    import x.component from x.path;
}
```

where y is from config file.  But this kind of import is impossible. Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Sorry but what is your question? It looks like you might be interested in [dynamic imports.](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like this is what I need. Will test it because I'm not sure.